# Move-Item causes "File Already Exists" error, despite folder having been deleted

Tags: file, powershell, directory, windows-7-x64, powershell-5.0

I have some code which deletes a folder, then copies files from a temporary directory to where that folder had been.

```
Remove-Item -Path '.\index.html' -Force
Remove-Item -Path '.\generated' -Force -Recurse  #folder containing generated files

#Start-Sleep -Seconds 10 #uncommenting this line fixes the issue

#$tempDir contains index.html and a sub folder, "generated", which contains additional files.  
#i.e. we're replacing the content we just deleted with new versions.
Get-ChildItem -Path $tempDir | %{
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $RelativePath -Force 
}
```

I get an intermittent error, `Move-Item : Cannot create a file when that file already exists.` on the Move-Item line for the `generated` path.

I've been able to prevent this by adding a hacky `Start-Sleep -Seconds 10` after the second `Remove-Item` statement; though that's not a great solution.

I assume the issue is that the Remove-Item statement completes / code moves on to the next line, before the OS has caught up with the actual file deletion; though that seems odd/worrying.  NB: There are ~2,500 files in the generated folder (all between 1-100 KBs).

There are no other processes accessing the folders (i.e. I've even closed my explorer windows & tested with this directory being excluded from my AV).

I've considered other options:

- using `Copy-Item` instead of `Move-Item`.  I don't like this as it requires creating new files when they're not required (i.e. a copy is slower than a move)... It's faster than my current sleep hack; but still not ideal.
- deleting the files & not the folder, then iterating through the subfolders & copying files to the new locations.  This would work, but is a lot more code for something that should be simple; so I don't want to pursue that option.
- Robocopy would do the trick; but I'd prefer a pure PowerShell solution.  This is the option I'll eventually pick if there is no clean solution though.

**Question**

- Has anyone seen this before?
- Is it a bug, or have I missed something?
- Is anyone aware of a fix / good workaround?

---

**Update**

Running the remove in a separate job (i.e. using the code below) did not resolve the issue.

```
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    Remove-Item -Path '.\index.html' -Force
    Remove-Item -Path '.\generated' -Force -Recurse  #folder containing generated files
} | Wait-Job | Out-Null

#$tempDir contains index.html and a sub folder, "generated", which contains additional files.  
#i.e. we're replacing the content we just deleted with new versions.
Get-ChildItem -Path $tempDir | %{
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $RelativePath -Force 
}
```

**Update #2**

Adding this works; i.e. rather than waiting a fixed time, we wait for the path to be removed / checking every second.  If it's not removed after 30 seconds we assume it's not going to be; so carry on regardless (which will cause the `move-item` to throw an error which gets handled elsewhere).

```
# ... remove-item code ...
Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
    param($Path)
    while(Test-Path $Path){start-sleep -Seconds 1}
} -ArgumentList '.\generated' | Wait-Job -Timeout 30 | Out-Null
# ... move-item code ...
```

Comment: Would you consider running the removal as a separate job? I don't know if the overhead of running in its own memory space would "fix" the issue because of the time taken or if would actually wait until the files were deleted.

Comment: @Matt: I'd be happy for that to run under a separate job so long as I could queue the Move-Item behind that job's completion (i.e. `start-job ... | wait-job | out-null; move-item ...`)... Will test now to see if that helps...

Comment: @Matt: sadly no joy on that approach (see amended question for the code I used).

Comment: @Matt: ps. I used your suggestion to tweak my sleep statement; i.e. taking advantage of the timeout option on `wait-job` to wait a max amount of time; whilst otherwise checking for the folder every second and continuing the moment it's gone...  Still very hacky so I'll leave this question open; but it does work.

Comment: This is probably a good solution. I would also run `Remove-Job * -force`, otherwise those hung-up jobs are just going to sit out there.

Answer (score 2):

In the end I settled for this solution; not perfect, but it works.

```
Remove-Item -Path '.\index.html' -Force
Remove-Item -Path '.\generated' -Force -Recurse  #folder containing generated files

#wait until the .\generated directory is full removed; or until ~30 seconds has elapsed
1..30 | %{
    if (-not (Test-Path -Path '.\generated' -PathType Container)) {break;}
    Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
}

Get-ChildItem -Path $tempDir | %{
    Move-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $RelativePath -Force 
}
```

This does the same as the job in update #2 of the question; only doesn't require the overhead of a job; just loops until the file's removed.

Here's the above logic wrapped as a reuable cmdlet:

```
function Wait-Item {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory, ValueFromPipeline, HelpMessage = 'The path of the item you wish to wait for')]
        [string]$Path
        ,
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'How many seconds to wait for the item before giving up')]
        [ValidateRange(1,[int]::MaxValue)]
        [int]$TimeoutSeconds = 30
        ,
        [Parameter(HelpMessage = 'By default the function waits for an item to appear.  Adding this switch causes us to wait for the item to be removed.')]
        [switch]$Remove
    )
    process {
        [bool]$timedOut = $true
        1..$TimeoutSeconds | %{
            if ((Test-Path -Path $Path) -ne ($Remove.IsPresent)){$timedOut=$false; return;}
            Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
        }
        if($timedOut) {
            Write-Error "Wait-Item timed out after $TimeoutSeconds waiting for item '$Path'"
        }
    }
}

#example usage:
Wait-Item -Path '.\generated' -TimeoutSeconds 30 -Remove
```

Comment: I'm not sure how it works. `break` breaks from a loop `%` is a shorthand for `Foreach-Object` which is not a loop but cmdlet. Thus, the `break` statement will break out *something else* in outer scope, which can be completely unexpected.